# .gitignore fails to ignore a file

Tags: git, windows-7, gitignore

I have a file, foo.php and it is located inside the bar foler, which is in the root folder of the project.

It was recently deleted by mistake, but I have re-created it, its path inside the folder is bar/foo.php

I have a row in `.gitignore`, stating that:

```
bar/foo.php
```

The path is correct, but if I run a

```
git status
```

the file is shown as a new file. How can I ignore it, if `.gitignore` fails to ignore it in its current version?

I am developing under Windows 7.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you stage it for commit before you added it to the .gitignore file?

Try the following command:

```
git rm --cached bar/foo.php
```

After that it should not be showing anymore when you run a `git status` if it is in the `.gitignore` correctly.

Comment: Both answers were correct, but I have chosen this one, because it was more descriptive. However, I have upvoted both.

Answer (score 1):

The File : 
`bar/foo.php`

Might still be in the git indexing. You can remove it from indexing by:

`git rm --cached bar/foo.php`